# Picking image from gallery in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a image view inside the view controller. I want to set this image when user selects an image from gallery.

I tried this code:

```
@IBOutlet var profilePicture: UIImageView!
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
    println("image selected from gallery")
    self.profilePicture.image = image
}
```

It prints debug message to console but it is not changing the image. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to assign image you got from gallery to your `UIImageView`.

```
@IBOutlet var profilePicture: UIImageView!
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    profilePicture.image = image

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in   
    })
    println("image selected from gallery")
    self.profilePicture.image=image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
@IBOutlet var profilePicture: UIImageView!
        func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

            })
            println("image selected from gallery")
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.profilePicture.image=image
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @IBAction func chooseProfilePicBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openCamera()
    }
    let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallary", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openGallary()
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
    }

    // Add the actions
    picker.delegate = self
    alert.addAction(cameraAction)
    alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func openCamera(){
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self .presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Warning"
        alert.message = "You don't have camera"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
    }
}
func openGallary(){
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//MARK:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
    picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageViewRef.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController){
    print("picker cancel.")
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to add this line of code at first of class :
var picker = UIImagePickerController()

Answer (score 0):

To display a selected image using UIImagePickerController use the following code:

```
// Add these protocols into your class declaration 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

// Set the delegate
@IBAction func presentViewImagePicker(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self 
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// Use these two methods from UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

Check the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageRetrieved.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imageRetrieved.image = pickedImage
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method you are using is deprecated. You should replace it with this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)info
```

[Use this link to learn which keys you need to use to retrieve the image from the dictionary.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)